# How to specify behavior of buttons in HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html

My page is coded out as such that everything I have is in a form.

```
<form onsubmit='return validate()' action='#' method='post'>
    <button class='accordian'>Drop Stuff1</button>
        <div class='panel'>
            //stuff here
        </div>
        <div>
            //stuff here too
        </div>
    <button class='accordian'>Drop Stuff2</button>
        <div class='panel'>
            //and here
        </div>
        <div>
            //and here too
        </div>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit!'>
</form>
```

The problem is that when I click on any button of the accordian, it runs my `validate()` function. How can I set it up so that the only time the `onsubmit='return validate()` part of the form is called is when my `<input type='submit' value='Submit!'` button is pressed by the user?

I've tried getting rid of `<form onsubmit='return validate()'` and placing that to my submit button, ie `<input type='submit' onsubmit='return validate()'` and I tried it with `onclick` instead as well. My pages keeps refreshing every time a panel of the accordian is pressed because it seems as if the form is submitting with every click. How can I circumvent this behavior and ensure that only the submit button dictates whether or not the form is to be submitted?

Comment: Why have you wrapped that all in a <form> tag?

Comment: @Adam can clearly see that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [default type of a button element is submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button). Change it instead to `button` and it won't submit the form and call your function.

E.g. `<button type="button" class='accordian'>Drop Stuff2</button>`

Answer (score 0):

add `type="button"` to the buttons

Answer (score 0):

The `onsubmit-event` triggers when an element of type `submit` is clicked. So just add `type="button"` to other buttons, because default is `submit`.

Answer (score 0):

and of course, the other option is to move the call to the validate function from the `<form>` tag to the `<intput>` tag

```
<form  action='#' method='post'>
    <button class='accordian'>Drop Stuff1</button>
        <div class='panel'>
            //stuff here
        </div>
        <div>
            //stuff here too
        </div>
    <button class='accordian'>Drop Stuff2</button>
        <div class='panel'>
            //and here
        </div>
        <div>
            //and here too
        </div>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit!' onclick='return validate();'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using button for accordian? Something else like div/span/li appears more easier for styling and more reasonable.